# How to write to an external text file in Android?

Tags: android

I want to write a string line in a text file in android project (using Eclipse). This is the code which i am trying but its not working...

```
    String s="hello azeem\n";
    try{
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("C:\\eventslog.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(s.getBytes());
    fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Duplicate of your post 20 minutes ago, [How to write to an external text file in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844476/how-to-write-to-an-external-text-file-in-android). Please don't repost; edit your original questions with clarifications instead.

Comment: Kindly tell me the solution if you have... I better thought to make new post and the problem is clearly described here.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to understand your question:

1. You want to write the file to c: drive in your computer - well **you can't**. If you want to save some file from android to your computer programmatic, you'll have to send it via network.
2. You want to write to some place in the android FS - in this case `c:\` is irreleveant, since this is a windows path, and android is unix based, meaning all paths start from root (`/`) also, android SDK provides you a few methods to access relevant directories files without using a fixed path. see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Let me clear my question a bit more: Actually there is file named eventslog.txt which is placed in C folder of my windows xp. I am writing an android test application with only one activity, I just need to write a line "hello world" to the file eventslog.txt... I need it because another application will use the data in this file later. Please tell me can i do this? thanks.

Comment: You will need a server on your windows PC and let your activity sending the data through TCP to your computer.

Comment: Can you tell me a link where i can find a complete tutorial on this (to use TCP for accomplish this task)? thanks.

Comment: Sure, look here: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/blog/2004/november/15.html and here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/139154-transfer-a-file-over-tcp/ I suggest you to take some general TCP sockets tutorial, since it is a very useful knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Write the text in Android to the device's sdcard. Use Android Bridge (adb.exe found in sdk\platform-tools) to pull the txt file onto your drive... in your case, a windows disk.

(write text to foo.txt in android)

in a command bar.bat:

```
adb pull /sdcard/Android/data/com.example.yourapp/files/foo.txt C:\foo.txt
```

Run the bar.bat file. That's it. foo.txt now exists on the sdcard and on C:\foo.txt

Sorry if this does not match your intent. You must invoke the batch file from Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you didn't add its permission...

this is here:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```