# Save network location as a .txt file (Without using GPS)

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I am a beginner in android programming. My Graduate project is about tracking a mobile device and i need the code to save the location( Without using GPS) as a text file. Someone suggest me the codes for doing that. It will be a great help for me.

Comment: Please search before asking a question, theres already answer for this available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756296/android-writing-logs-to-text-file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844579/how-to-write-to-an-external-text-file-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580683/android-java-writing-text-file-to-sd-card

Comment: @Ruuhkis Thank u. But my project needs to save a txt file with network location details. Kindly help me.

Comment: You can easily save the network details on text file just like you can print it out. see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try this.

```
locationManagerNetwork = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location2 = locationManagerNetwork
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

     if (location2 != null) {       
                String message = String
                        .format("Yout location : \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                                location2.getLongitude(), location2.getLatitude());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();


    //use here file writer if you want to write the coordinates in a text file
            }
```

---

for writing sd card

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File f = new File(sdcard, "/yourfile");

if(!f.exsist()){
f.createNewFile();
//Use outwriter here, outputstream search how to write into a file in java code 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

only way to do that is to play with telephony manager and see what kind of information you can get about cell tower or network. Every network tower have unique id to it and from that you might be able to get an approx estimation depending upon signal strength and stuff of person's location.

I bet it'll be fun and tricky business.

Comment: Is there any way to find the approx network location using code. I have tried many codes. Nothing works.

Comment: Many codes and methods described by stackoverflow users. Please help me bro.

Comment: do you have a specific question though?

Comment: I want to take the Service Provider Network Location and save it to the SD card as a .txt file.

Comment: can you post some example data you get from telephony manager, from there we might be able to figure out something

Comment: check this post, https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/ASVpv7RbLL8