# how to get raw folder uri path and save in internal memory in android?

Tags: android

here my code.where is my errors errors.the errors is file not found exception.

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.ring.app/raw/"+a[i]+".mp3");
file= new File(video.toString());
try 
{ 
inputStream= new FileInputStream(file);
fos = super.openFileOutput("output"+i+".mp3", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
byte buffer[]=new byte[1024];
while((len=inputStream.read(buffer))>0)
fos.write(buffer,0,len);
fos.close();
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9734268/1172945) answer

Comment: @Androider do u get your solution ?

Comment: @gtumca-MAC no. i searching now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raw folder url path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966085/raw-folder-url-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.filename;
```

Comment: Was that pdf answer enough for you?

Comment: @SpK Thanks dude but i gets junk character in pdf...not original content

Comment: i will give you bounty points sure if not get better solution till tomorrow

Comment: Okay. I'll also try to provide exact answer for you. I'm also trying for this.