# Android Studio Saving Data to Phone

Tags: android, string, save, storage

```
String myString = "hello world";
```

How could I save the contents of `myString` into a **.txt** file within the Phone/Android, which will be there after the application ends and so that I can edit the value in future?

Comment: have you gone through [all these](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1PRFC_enIN628IN629&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=write%20file%20in%20android%20example) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write to an external text file in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844579/how-to-write-to-an-external-text-file-in-android)

Comment: why there is word Android studio in question? The question seems to be about app and Android device/phone...

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
public void WriteToFile(String str)
    try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
private String readFromFile() {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("config.txt");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```